# Jquery using css function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So im just playing around with my jquery and got stuck with quite odd problem. so i'm getting width of div like this

```
block_width = $(".grid_block").css("width");
```

Now i would like to do something with that width let's say

```
container_width = block_width * 21;
```

and now if would alert `container_width` i would get `Nah` insted of numbers, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing I have done with `width()`

```
var block_width = $(".grid_block").width();
var container_width = block_width * 21;
alert(container_width)
```

[Try this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwayB/)

Answer (score 5):

You're getting `NaN` instead of numbers because the width value you receive will be a string including units

I.E.:

```
"500px"
"3em"
"27.2%"
```

You *could* parse the number with `parseInt`

```
width = ...css('width');
width = parseInt(width);
```

But this is completely unnecessary because jQuery has the [`width` method](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```
width = ...width(); //numeric value
```

Answer (score 5):

`.css("width")` returns a string representing the width, with `"px"` appended, i.e. `"___px"`.  Multiplying that string with some number fails (`"12px" * 2` evaluates to `NaN`).

You could look into the functions `.width()` to get the width, and `.width(x)` to set the width (both as numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a string as a part of a math operation...

Try this:

```
block_width = parseInt($(".grid_block").css("width"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css("width") returns a string, not a number. Convert it using parseInt/parseFloat or use jquery .width() function (which returns number).

Comment: hmm that's strange because if i would try to alert block_width i would get numbers, anyways thanks for quick answer

Comment: You could check `typeof(block_width)`, this is string in case you're querying css method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the px from the end and do a parseInt before your multiplication

```
block_width = block_width.replace("px", "")
container_width = parseInt(block_width) * 21;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jquery width() method.The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px).
Please check http://api.jquery.com/width/
No need to do parsing for getting the width as other posts suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is because block_width is of int type;

```
    block_width = intParse($(".grid_block").css("width").replace('px'));
    container_width = block_width * 21
```

or event better

```
block_width = $(".grid_block").width();
container_width = block_width * 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
I came over the same problem. `.css("width")` returns "20px" for example. What I did, which is sure a bit odd and you could probably solve this with regex but what I did was :

```
var newWidth = parseInt(($('something').css("width")).split("px")[0])+xx;//xx... Size you want to add
$('something').css("width",newWidth);
```

I mean you could to everything in one Line also without initializing a new variable but if somebody wants to read your code and is not into jquery or javascript yet, I think its better to split it up.
Hope this helps you !